# Websphere Application Server 404 JSPG0036E "failed to find resource" error

Tags: web-applications, websphere, virtualhost, websphere-8, contextroot

I'm trying to deploy an application war in my local WAS (v8.5) and it looked like it went okay and the enterprise application starts up fine. The jsp pages are present inside the new war folders.
When I try to access it using the url `http://localhost:9080/LocalApp/LocalPage.jsp` I get this error

> [12/19/14 10:30:42:185 EST]     FFDC Exception:com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.JSPErrorReport SourceId:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters -SER ProbeId:1047 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManagerImpl@78967916
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.JSPErrorReport: JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource /LocalApp/LocalPage.jsp
>       at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.findWrapper(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:447)
>       at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.getServletWrapper(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:338)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:965)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource /LocalApp/LocalPage.jsp
>       ... 22 more

I had originally tried this with the URL `http://localhost:9080/LocalPage.jsp` and I had the same issue.
I then defined a context root with value "/LocalApp" using Application-->Enterprise Applications-->App name-->Context Root for Web Modules

I've also tried defining a virtual host using Virtual Hosts-->New Virtual Host and I defined a host alias with port 9180. I mapped the application to this virtual host but the port doesn't open up in my local system.

What steps am I missing?

Comment: Did you repulished, restarted application and server after change of the context? Adding alias in virtual hosts will not create new port. You would have to add transport chain, so stick to the default_host and 9080.

Comment: Please add more details, particularly where is LocalPage.jsp located. If it is under WEB-INF directory, you cannot access it directly from URL, you need at least a servlet to redirect it to that page (or some MVC framework, such as Spring MVC, Struts 2 etc).

Answer (score 0):

When you install the application in the configuration make sure you check the checkbox for **Allow EJB reference target to resolve automatically**